# NSCollectionView resizing items like iTunes

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

Is it possible to have NSCollectionView resize the items dynamically?  I want it to behave like iTunes where the items can range from let's say 120 wide to 160 wide, but if it goes below 120, it resets to 160 and loses a column, and if it gets bigger than 160, it resets to 120 and adds a column.

Right now my collection view will add and remove columns as its width changes, but it doesn't resize the actual items.